# hoverintent is not working, despite including two arguments

Tags: jquery, hover

What am I doing incorrectly here.  It is telling me that I have a cfg.out error

```
$(function(){

var neighborhoodSlide = function(evt){
if ( $('#neighborhoods').is(':hidden')) {
  $('#neighborhoods').slideDown(350);
  }
else{
  $('#neighborhoods').slideUp(350);
}
return { mouseenter: neighborhoodSlide, mouseleave: neighborhoodSlide };
}  


$('.hood').hoverIntent(neighborhoodSlide);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `hoverIntent` takes a second function argument:

```
.hoverIntent( overFunc, [timeOutInMs,] outFunc );
```

Since it looks like you're grouping the hide/show behavior in a single function, you could either break that up into two:

```
$('.hood').hoverIntent(neighborhoodSlideOver, neighborhoodSlideOut );
```

...or perhaps supply the same function for both arguments:

```
$('.hood').hoverIntent(neighborhoodSlide, neighborhoodSlide );
```

You can also supply an empty function for either event:

```
$('.hood').hoverIntent(neighborhoodSlide, function(){} );
```

Comment: yeah ken, I was trying to return a dictionary of two functions from the first argument.  I guess that doesn't work in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @Brendan, you might be able to return a `config` object with properties `over`, `timeout`, and `out`, and supply that single object as an argument. See [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).